# Is the 21 Bitcoin computer using Core or Classic?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-classic, 21-bitcoin-computer

The 21 Bitcoin computer is using Core, right? I can't find any information that says otherwise. Can someone please confirm this for me though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed so myself since the alternatives were not in a mature stage (technically and/or socially accepted) when 21 released their computer.

However, in their [tutorial](https://21.co/learn/21-full-node/) they do say that you will have a Bitcoin Core full node running at the end.

Comment: Ahh excellent, that was exactly the kind of link that I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile Bitcoin Classic from source and got it up and running with these steps: https://gist.github.com/redsquirrel/75b5192764b17c6ea265